# Ionic 1 App - Changing Tab Color

Tags: android, css, ionic-framework, tabs

I'm responsible for our university's freshman-week-app, which is build with Ionic 1. It has 5 Ttab-items, and I want to change the color of these tabs. I have used the custom.css file for that:

```
.tab-item.tab-item-active, .tab-item.active, .tab-item.activated, .tabs-md-tab-text-color-active, .tabs-md-tab-icon-color-active {
color: cyan;
background: #e72167; }
```

Now my Problem:

The Color changes...

[1] ...Work on iOS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXRvA.png

but

[2] ...don't work on Android: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OuXr.png

I've googled for hours and tried several CSS attributes, but nothing works. Can anyone tell me a tab-color attibute that also works on Android, or a different solution? Thanks!

Comment: * the tab color changes also work when viewing the app in-browser: [...Work https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oh7o.png

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are not updating the css file of iOS folder only. To reflect changes on both platform you must change css of root folder and files. Changing on root level files automatically reflects for platform else only specific plaform will be updated respectively. When you type ionic serve command, this pushes the changes to the platform level. If root level don't have changes that you want that will update remaining platform. I hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

add style to .tab-item-active class like this

```
.tab-item-active{
  background:green;
}
```

see this codepen:http://codepen.io/edisonpappi/pen/aWvmjz